# JavaScript Loop issue with variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, each

So, I have this jQuery `.each` loop, and for the most part its working as intended; there is one issue, but first the loop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Pushpin(){}
            Pushpin.prototype.XZX = {
                site: null,
                getHtmlDescription: function () {
                    var html  = '<b id="infoboxTitle" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:220px;">' + this.site.Name + '</b>';
                        html += '<a id="infoboxDescription" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px; width:220px; height:120px;">{0}</a>';

                    var description = 'Headcount: ' + this.site.Headcount + '<br />';
                    description += 'Leases: ' + this.site.LeaseCount + '<br />';

                    html = html.replace('{0}', description);

                    return html;
                }
            };

            var data = [
                    {"Address":{"City":"Atlanta","Country":"USA","County":"","Latitude":33.9882404987503,"Longitude":-84.1629638209203,"Region":"Southeast","State":"GA","StreetAddress":"Atlanta 177","ZipCode":"30096"},"Headcount":0,"ImageBytes":null,"ImageRefPath":"","LeaseCount":1,"Leases":null,"Name":"Atlanta","NextExpire":"\/Date(1495083600000-0500)\/","Number":"1052","PrimaryUse":"Garage","PropertyID":"OMNI","RecID":32839,"RecordID":1004,"RentableSquareFootage":22000,"SiteRecordID":"DEMO_29626","SiteTotalDollars":0,"Status":null,"Type":"LSE"},
                    {"Address":{"City":"Bellevue","Country":"USA","County":"","Latitude":47.6043250620083,"Longitude":-122.14236047437,"Region":"Northwest","State":"WA","StreetAddress":"Seattle 51","ZipCode":"98007"},"Headcount":0,"ImageBytes":null,"ImageRefPath":"","LeaseCount":1,"Leases":null,"Name":"Bellevue","NextExpire":"\/Date(1260424800000-0600)\/","Number":"1078","PrimaryUse":"Tower","PropertyID":"OMNI","RecID":32865,"RecordID":1027,"RentableSquareFootage":7652,"SiteRecordID":"DEMO_275651","SiteTotalDollars":0,"Status":null,"Type":"LSE"}
                ]; 

            var mylist = []; 
             $.each(data, function (i, item) { 
                try {
                    var pin = new Pushpin();  
                    pin.XZX.site = item;
                    mylist.push(pin); 
                } catch (e) { alert (e); } 
             });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#btnAlert').click(function () { 
                    $('#content').html(mylist[$('#index').val()].XZX.getHtmlDescription());
                } );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:300px;">
            <div style="position:relative; width:250px;">
                <select id="index">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                </select> 

                <input type="submit" id="btnAlert"/>
            </div>
            <div id="content" style="position:relative;width:250px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also available on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8YS2/

At the end of the loop, `mylist[x].site` for any `x` all point to the same instance of my data item, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that each `pin.XYZ` is the *same* object -- namely `Pushpin.prototype.XYZ`.

The simple "fix" is to use:

```
var pin = new Pushpin(...)
pin.XYZ = {
   site: item
   // the following will get tedious fast, consider one of the "property copy"
   // implementations floating about -- including jQuery.extend   
   getHtmlDescription: Pushpin.prototype.XYZ.getHtmlDescription
}
```

Which will assign a *new* object to the `XYZ` property of each *new* Pushpin object. Of course, this could be designed differently as well :)

At the very least, move `XYZ` off the Pushpin.prototype object -- this will allow it to treated nicely as an object (the way that `this` is passed about actually makes it nigh-impossible for a function dangling off an object of a prototype to access instance data of the object to which the prototype applies); the end-code might look something like:

```
// We .. "wrap" the real Pushpin constructor
// somewhere global after Bing Mapi JS loaded
Pushpin = (function (bingPushpin) {
   return function Pushpin (...) {
       var pin = new bingPushpin(...)
       pin.XYZ = new XYZ()
       // trick of "returning" from ctor
       return pin
   }
})(PushPin)
// ...
var pin = new Pushpin(...)
pin.XYZ.site = item
```

Happy coding.

---

Pre-update answer:

This actually isn't a scoping issue -- there are no inadvertent closures created and each expression is strictly evaluated.

I suspect there is another problem, such as unexpected input (data contains a bunch of the *same item*) or flawed assumption (such that objects are magically cloned) or something unrelated.

Happy coding.

---

Analysis:

```
 var mylist = [];
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
     // creates new object
     var pin = new Pushpin(x, y);
     // property of new object assigned
     // remember that no "duplication" is occurring
     pin.site = item;
     // new object pushed to array
     mylist.push(pin);
 });
```

Therefor, no `pin` will be the same *but it is possible that `item` evaluates to the same object each loop*. (The *only exception* to this is if the Pushpin constructor uses `return` to return an existing object, which would be a fun fine indeed.)

Comment: The Pushpin is from Bing Maps (not sure if it uses `return` or not). I have verified that `item` is different each time through the loop.

Comment: @Nate Don't worry about the Pushpin ctor then -- it would break everything in terribly wonderful ways. Do you have a *minimal* test-case showing the behavior? (http://jsfiddle.net is a good place to post it, as well as in the original post). For the test-case it should be sufficient to use `var pin = {}` and remove the Bing Maps dependency.

Comment: No, I'll try to get one. Would it make a difference if my `.each` loop is in the callback for a `$.getJSON` call?

Comment: @Nate Not inherently, but the larger context may contain more clues.

Comment: OK, I have a test-case that demonstrates the behavior I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/M8YS2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to declare the var pin outside of the .each?
then set it to new inside the .each.

```
var pin;
 var mylist = [];
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
     try {
         pin = new Pushpin(x, y);
         pin.site = item;
         mylist.push(pin);
     } catch (e) { alert (e); }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're within a function I would say yes of course they all point to the same object as you're only passing by reference. After looking around I stumbled upon this - http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165 - but it doesn't look like there is a straight-forward option for cloning a Javascript object.

Perhaps your best approach would be to write a function that clones an input object and returns it as a new instance?

Comment: Pedantic: Objects in JavaScript are not passed by reference (a reference is an underlying implementation technique/detail that is never exposed in the JavaScript language). Rather, JavaScript objects are passed as *themselves* (not a copy, clone or duplicate). This calling behavior is known as [Pass-By-Object or Pass-By-Object-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

Answer (score 0):

After reading MoarCodePlz's answer I thought maybe this could help getting around the 'by reference' issue. Haven't verified it though.

```
 var mylist = [];
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
     // Creates the new object as a part of yourlist
     mylist.push(new Pushpin(x, y));
     // property of new object assigned item
     mylist[x].site = item;
 });
```

Comment: This won't fix anything. An assignment *never* creates a new object (primitive values can be excluded from the discussion for simplicity).

Comment: Okay. Thought it was worth a try. :)